How do I assign multiple variables to a single argument in a function in python?
I am trying to make a program where it takes a trinomial and factors it, if possible. Whenever the user inputs A, B, and C, the trinomial is supposed to be taken through the factor(product, summation) function. I don’t want to use the quadratic formula, as I’ve already made that. Instead, my goal is to use the X method where you multiply A and C for the top, and use B for the bottom. Then, you find two numbers that add to get (A*C) and add to get B. The user is supposed to enter A, B, and C, and then the equation is taken through the for loop to find the two numbers that multiply to get one and add to get another. I can't seem to figure out how to assign A and C to the product arg and B to the summation.
import math
import cmath

def factor(product, summation):
        
  for i in range(-abs(product), abs(product) + 1):
    if i == 0:
            continue
    if product % i == 0:  # Ensure i is a factor of the product
            j = product // i  # Find the corresponding factor
            if i + j == summation:  # Check if the sum of the factors matches the given summation
                return i, j
    return None
  

#Assign the coefficients
print('Follow this format: Ax^2 + Bx + C')

a = float(input('Enter A: '))
b = float(input('Enter B: '))
c = float(input('Enter C: '))



#Give a space between everything
print(' ')
print (f'{a}x^2 + {b}x + {c}')

factor(product, summation)

I tried declaring different variables outside the function, product = (a*c) and summation = b, but it doesn't make sense and I am overall lost on how to tie all of this together.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Please [edit] your question to include more details about what you expect to happen vs what's actually happening. What does it mean to "assign multiple variables to a single argument"?

What is stopping you from writing factor(a*c, b)

Please check. Now I've edited my answer and given the conventional approach as well.

@AndrewYim, I edited the post and added more details on what should happened and what is my goal with this program.

Edit: I've given the conventional approach as well(in the way you tried)
It's easy to resolve. I'm using a better formula for finding the roots of the quadretic equation(trinomial). i.e
-b ± √(b²-4ac)
_________________
     2a

Code:
a = int(input('a'))
b = int(input('b'))
c = int(input('c'))
x_1 = (-1*b + ((b**2-4*a*c))**(1/2))/(2*a)
x_2 = (-1*b - ((b**2-4*a*c))**(1/2))/(2*a)
op = f'the roots of the given equation {a}x\u00b2 + {b}x + {c} are:\n {x_1} and {x_2}'
print(op)

Input & Output in python interpreter:
a
4
b
16
c
-9
the roots of the given equation 4x² + 16x + -9 are:
 0.5 and -4.5

Note: x\u00b2 is given to get the alt code of x²
You can use the same logic if you want to do with iteration.
Edit : As you preferred conventional method, I've given below the conventional approach:
def factor(product, summation):

    prod_ref = abs(product)
    factors = []
    i = 1
    l = prod_ref
    while i <= prod_ref:
        if prod_ref % i == 0:
            l = i 
            m = prod_ref/i
            factors.append([l,m])
        i += 1
    if product > 0 and summation > 0: pass
    elif product > 0 and summation < 0:
        for i in range(len(factors)):
            factors[i][0] = -1*factors[i][0]
            factors[i][1] = -1*factors[i][1]
    elif product < 0 and summation < 0:
        for i in range(len(factors)):
            big = max(factors[i])
            idx = factors[i].index(big)
            factors[i][idx] = -1*big
    else:
        for i in range(len(factors)):
            small = min(factors[i])
            idx = factors[i].index(small)
            factors[i][idx] = -1*small
    
    
    for x in factors:
        if sum(x) == summation:           
            
            roots = (((-1*x[0])/a),((-1*x[1])/a))
            break

    return roots


a = int(input('Enter A: '))
b = int(input('Enter B: '))
c = int(input('Enter C: '))


product = a*c 
summation = b
#Give a space between everything
print(' ')
print (f'{a}x^2 + {b}x + {c}')

roots = factor(product, summation)
print(roots)

